# How to implement this mysql query?

Tags: mysql

Insert Into table if a duplicate exits select that row primary key else insert into that table and return last insert id ?

```
    SELECT  IF  (EXISTS(SELECT * FROM users  WHERE userName='adminchat')) THEN

BEGIN

SELECT userId FROM users  WHERE userName='adminchat';

end;

ELSE

BEGIN

INSERT INTO `users`( `userRole`, `userName`, `createdOn`, `emailId`, `is_active`, `password`) VALUES (1,'user1_chat',NOW(),'sdmd1@sdmd1.com',1,'123456') 
select LAST_INSERT_ID();

END;
```

Answer (score 1):

If a table contains an AUTO_INCREMENT column and INSERT ... UPDATE inserts a row, the LAST_INSERT_ID() function returns the AUTO_INCREMENT value. If the statement updates a row instead, LAST_INSERT_ID() is not meaningful. However, you can work around this by using LAST_INSERT_ID(expr). Suppose that id is the AUTO_INCREMENT column. To make LAST_INSERT_ID() meaningful for updates, insert rows as follows:

```
INSERT INTO table (a,b,c) VALUES (1,2,3)
  ON DUPLICATE KEY UPDATE id=LAST_INSERT_ID(id), c=3;
```

A way to make things work is to use a dummy column,
so if you have a table with auto_increment column ID and unique key a,b and a smallint dummy column for instance, the query might look like this:

```
INSERT INTO test (a,b) VALUES ('1','2') ON DUPLICATE KEY UPDATE ID=LAST_INSERT_ID(ID),Dummy = NOT dummy;
Now, SELECT LAST_INSERT_ID(); will return the correct ID.
```

Comment: Sorry bro i didnt get your answer can you elaborate on that

Comment: It is a trick to use to do an update using INSERT....ON DUPLICATE KEY UPDATE which manges to trigger the LAST_INSERT_ID to return the id of the updated row.

Comment: @Kickstart Bro that is not my point what i want to do is to check if a row exists if it exists i want that rows primary key not last insert id in that case if it did not exist i want to add that row and in that case i want the last insert id

Comment: Why do you want to check the row exists? If it doesn't exist then a normal insert works fine, and if it does exist then using this trick the LAST_INSERT_ID will return the existing rows ID (not the id of the inserted row).

Comment: Bro If the row exits then i want its primary key in else case insert on insert get the last inser id

Comment: @Kickstart Bro check Out

Comment: If the row exists then this trick means LAST_INSERT_ID() does get the existing rows id field. However it now appears that if one row doesn't exist you want to insert a completely different row.